# Sending a Proactive Message as a result of a dialog prompt choice

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm pretty new to Microsoft Bot Framework. I have a bot that receives messages from one user and can be viewed by another. I want to add a feature where the viewer can then reply to the sender. I figured the best way to do this is to send a proactive message to the original sender. However, I'm having trouble understanding the documentation Microsoft provides and other sources are pretty dated.

Right now this is what I have.

> MessageDetails.RelatesTo contains the ConversationReference:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var messageDetails = (MessageDetails)stepContext.Options;



    var replyText = (string)stepContext.Result;

    var messageactivity = messageDetails.RelatesTo.GetContinuationActivity();

    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"{messageDetails.RelatesTo}");

    var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(messageactivity.ServiceUrl));
    if (messageDetails.IsTrustedServiceUrl)
    {
        MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(messageactivity.ServiceUrl);
    }



    var triggerReply = messageactivity.CreateReply();
    triggerReply.Text = $"NoReply from {stepContext.Context.Activity.Name}: {replyText}";

    await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(triggerReply);

    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Your reply has been sent to {messageDetails.RelatesTo.User.Name}.");

    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(messageDetails, cancellationToken);
}
```

This code doesn't work and I'm not entirely sure why. (I would also appreciate any advice on how I might troubleshoot the problem). I realize that this doesn't make use of the controller shown in the sample code provided by Microsoft. Honestly, I don't understand how the notify controller works. So if a solution involves that, it would be great to get an explanation on some of the details.

Comment: What error are you running into? If you can share a link to your repo or email me your code, I might be able to debug faster. Looking into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fixing Your Problem

My guess is that you're getting this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: clientId'

This is because you're not specifying the `appId` in `new ConnectorClient`. You can disregard that, as you're better off doing something more like:

```cs
await stepContext.Context.Adapter.ContinueConversationAsync("<yourAppId>", messageDetails.RelatesTo, async (ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancel) =>
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(triggerReply);
}, cancellationToken);
```

The key is making sure you have a [`ConversationReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.conversationreference?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) for the user that you need to send the proactive message to. If you don't have one, you should be able to [`CreateConversation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.botframeworkadapter.createconversationasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_BotFrameworkAdapter_CreateConversationAsync_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Bot_Connector_Authentication_MicrosoftAppCredentials_Microsoft_Bot_Schema_ConversationParameters_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_BotCallbackHandler_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) to establish one

Note that you also have:

```cs
if (messageDetails.IsTrustedServiceUrl)
{
    MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(messageactivity.ServiceUrl);
}
```

This is basically saying, "if we already trust the serviceUrl, trust it again". Instead, you need: `if (!messageDetails.IsTrustedServiceUrl)`

---

#### How [Proactive Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) Works

Here's a brief explanation of how the proactive sample works. I recommend downloading it and playing around with it to get a better understanding.

1. The bot establishes listeners on [`api/messages`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/BotController.cs) (all bots do this) and [`api/notify`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs) (only this bot does this).
2. When a user messages the bot, it goes through `api/messages` and [is processed](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/BotController.cs#L32) through the [`ActivityHandler`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Bots/ProactiveBot.cs#L13).
3. On any message, the bot [saves the conversation reference](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Bots/ProactiveBot.cs#L13)
4. When somebody visits `<theBotUrl>/api/notify`, it [loops through each saved conversation reference](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Bots/ProactiveBot.cs#L13), [calls ContinueConversation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L44), and [sends the message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L58) to all of the users in the saved conversation references

Comment: Thanks it's working now. I ended up using the ContinueConversationAsync line. Probably should have realized that stepContext had an adapter in there somewhere.

Comment: best explanation of How Proactiv Bot works I've seen so far!